# Object not following the Nurbspath but there is a blue line moving

Tags: animation, objects, path, makehuman, nurbs-surface

The human is still in position but the blue line is moving.

[image: The human is still in position but the blue line is moving.]

The human isn't moving, but the blue line is moving. What should I do?

Comment: Hello maybe change the Forward Axis in the constraint or please share your file